# Django : Using Mongodb with django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I just start looking at mongo db for the Django backend.

I have few questions .

1.Can i use raw mongo db instead os using Django ORM for the queryset .

2.My application is realted to Electronic health record so somone  can add many details somone will not add anything (Basicaaly it should  not database field dependent .)Please help me in this case how should I Design my Model . Or Instead of using Model can I directly  fetch and data using raw mongo db queries from the Django view ?

I go through some blog post and found it is working somewhat ok .
  But .
    Can I insert some field in the database which is not defined in the Django Model .

Really confuse .

Any help and suggestionn would be appriciated .

Comment: Please dont forget to write your comment before marking as negative .This will help user to improve the question quality

Answer (score 7):

There are various framework you can adopt when you want to use MongoDB for Django. Listed are some of the framework you might consider.

- [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/)
- [django-mongodb-engine](http://www.django-mongodb.org)
- [Ming](http://merciless.sourceforge.net/)
- [MongoKit](http://namlook.github.com/mongokit/index.html)

You can use directly access MangoDB without going through Django ORM, however it is better to use proper interface. Wrappers like PyMango and Ming enables you to take the advantage of dynamic behavior and provides a API to guarante of the type of data in a collection.

Selecting a framework will help you develop in confidence.

[PyMango](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6/index.html) is a light weight wrapper and would provide you faster execution. However if you are looking for an ORM then [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) or MongoKit or Ming.

Comment: You may be interested in consider some new frameworks that have recently sprung up. You can integrate Django with MongoDB by adding just one line of code using [Djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) There is no need to replace the Django ORM with a new ORM (like MongoEngine) using this approach.